# How do i get the value in the <li> tag in razor components?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-components

I want to get the element inside the li tag on button click from the same li tag in razor components

I want to display li tag element value with inputText on clicking display button

```
@page "/questions"

<ul>
    @foreach(var item in list)
    {
        <li>@item <input bind="@inputText"/><button onclick="@Display">Display</button></li>
    }

</ul>



@functions{
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "Hello",
        "World"
    };

    string inputText = "";


    void Display()
    {
        //item + inputText
    }


}
```

I want to display li item text along wiht inputText on clicking display button

Comment: Are you wanting the text in the controller or the html?  Are you wanting to get the text with js or c#?

Comment: I want to get the text with c# and i want text in controller for further processing of text.